# service httpd status shows internal server error

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I have a dedicated server. No PHP files were running when i use my website so i tried looking into the apache and used `service https status` to check apache status and this is what i am getting
service httpd status

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, root@mps-vm1 and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

```
Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fipsmod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Can someone please tell me what should i do?

Comment: You should do as it says and look in the error log.

Comment: I'm confused: this error is displayed by the browser, while "service httpd status" should be typed into a terminal (and the answer should be one of "httpd is running (pid xxxx)" or "httpd not running")

Comment: no this message is displayed in the SSH terminal(putty)

Comment: IMHO your configuration is messed up. Start examinig "/etc/init.d/httpd", to discover why the error 500 comes up asking the pid of httpd (that is what service httpd status does)

Comment: @AndrewQ, Start by looking the the logs - they should contain valuable information about the error, it's location etc

Answer (score 0):

`service httpd status` will be retrieving Apache's /server-status/ page (provided by `mod_status`). It will be doing this via `apachectl status` (or apache2ctl if you're on Debian or Ubuntu)

This likely means that your configuration is not loadable. You can use `apachectl configtest` to test a configuration before reloading/restarting the webserver.

The error message, by default, will also be found in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` (or ssl_error_log, depending on how the request came in.) Those should be your first point of call in a situation such as this.

Comment: It could be a file called error.log (or something completely different too).

Answer (score -1):

So I solved the issue by reinstalling APACHE. That seemed to be the only way. Maybe when I was making changes to the installation files, I did something terribly wrong and messed up Apache.